# FORECAST worksheet function not working - Unable to get Forecast property of worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to loop through columns forecasting data in VBA. When there were 3 columns, this worked originally, I expanded to 6 columns and it is now not functioning.
I also tried a variant using a single loop for the forecasting and using Select Case to loop through all the columns.

```
    Sub forecast_daily()

    'refresh values (specifically Today and matching index)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


    'set sheets

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Data")
    Set fc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Intake Forecasting Daily")

    ' define values

    Dim dates, newdates, EUSSIntake, JFMintake, lateintake, newjfmintake, convertintake, BNOintake,      Akinintake, Chenintake, ibtexintake, zambintake, velajintake As Range
     Dim i, j As Long
    Dim newdate As Double
    Dim Rownum, a As Integer
    Dim negcheck As Double
    Dim toggleB, toggleC, toggleD, toggleE, toggleF, toggleG As Boolean



    'Find empty row in EUSSIntake
    i = fc.Range("V3").Value
    'i equals empty row number

    newdate = Cells(i, 1)

    Set dates = Range("A22", "A" & (i - 1))
    Set EUSSIntake = Range("B22", "B" & (i - 1))

    'change starting point for JFM and BNO to account for blanks
    Set newdates = Range("A1065", "A" & (i - 1))
    Set JFMintake = Range("C1065", "C" & (i - 1))
    Set BNOintake = Range("D1065", "D" & (i - 1))

    'change start point for EUSS split (922)
    Set dates3 = Range("A922", "A" & (i - 1))
    Set lateintake = Range("E922", "E" & (i - 1))
    Set newjfmintake = Range("F922", "F" & (i - 1))
    Set convertintake = Range("G922", "G" & (i - 1))


    ' Loop Worksheet forecast function
    toggleB = True
    toggleC = True
    toggleD = True
    toggleE = True
    toggleF = True
    toggleG = True



    ' This is main loop - This originally worked! Frustrating now that it is isnt.     
    While i < 3001
        If Cells(i - 1, 2) > -1000 And toggleB = True Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(newdate, EUSSIntake, dates)
        Else
        toggleB = False
        End If
        If Cells(i - 1, 3) > -1000 And toggleC = True Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(newdate, JFMintake, newdates)
        Else
        toggleC = False
        End If
        If Cells(i - 1, 4) > -1000 And toggleD = True Then
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(newdate, BNOintake, newdates)
        Else
        toggleD = False
        End If
        If Cells(i - 1, 5) > -1000 And toggleE = True Then
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(newdate, lateintake, dates3)
        Else
        toggleE = False
        End If
        If Cells(i - 1, 6) > -1000 And toggleF = True Then
        Cells(i, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(newdate, newjfmintake, dates3)
        Else
        toggleF = False
        End If
        If Cells(i - 1, 7) > -1000 And toggleG = True Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(newdate, convertintake, dates3)
        Else
        toggleG = False
        End If

    ' increment i
        i = i + 1
    
    ' Update new values
       newdate = Cells(i, 1)
    
    Wend
    
    
    End Sub
```

I have tried the usual reasons for this error. Newdate is passing in as a double, knownx and knowny and ranges of equal size for the forecast function. Im pulling my hair out that it worked 2 days ago and ive changed nothing and now its throwing the error.

Comment: Without data, I cannot reproduce your problem. But that is likely where the issue arises. If you edit your post to include source data and desired output, be sure to enter the data as text. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Unfortunately the data involved is government data used for work. Although they are just ranges of numeric values.

Comment: Although government data is usually public, you don't have to use real data to demonstrate your problem. You should provide sample data that is representative and can be used to duplicate your problem. Make it easy for a volunteer to help you.